# How to remove a label that is within a function when the function is run again

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to remove a label each time the function is called. Currently it displays the saving location. If a user selects the saving location again, both the new and old labels will be visible. I want to remove the old label when the function is called again.

Below is my code but it isn't working as intended.

```py
#clear output path
def clear_output_path():
    outputPathText.pack_forget()


#Select Saving Location 
def SavingLocation():
    clear_output_path()
    global output_path 
    outputPath = ""
    output_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    outputPathText = ttk.Label(root, text="Saving Location:" + output_path) 
    outputPathText.pack()
```

Comment: There is something wrong with: `outputPathText.pack_forget()`. Why does this not produce a symbol error?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to delete and recreate the label, instead of creating it once and then just changing the text on the label?

Comment: I honestly didn't think of just changing the text of a label, I'm a noob sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because you are creating a new outputPathText label every time the SavingLocation function is called, but you are not keeping track of the old labels, so they remain in the view.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Label Example")

# Create a global variable to keep track of the label
outputPathText = None

# Clear output path
def clear_output_path():
    global outputPathText
    if outputPathText:
        outputPathText.pack_forget()
        outputPathText = None

# Select Saving Location
def SavingLocation():
    clear_output_path()
    global output_path
    output_path = ""
    output_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    global outputPathText
    outputPathText = ttk.Label(root, text="Saving Location:" + output_path)
    outputPathText.pack()

# Create a button to trigger the SavingLocation function
button = ttk.Button(root, text="Select Saving Location", command=SavingLocation)
button.pack()

# Start the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

1. I added a global variable outputPathText to keep track of the label.
2. In the clear_output_path function, I check if outputPathText exists,
   and if it does, I use the pack_forget() method to remove it from the
   view.
3. In the SavingLocation function, I set outputPathText as global to
   modify the global variable. If there is an existing label, it's
   removed before creating a new one. This ensures that only one label
   is visible at a time.

With these changes, you should be able to remove the old label when the function is called again.